# Probability of COVID-19 spread

Tags: covid-19

Is it possible (or reasonable) to calculate the probability of COVID-19 carrier who is asymptomatic infecting more number of persons it comes in contact with than a symptomatic carrier would do during the same specified period of 15 days. Is that a likely scenario in this pandemic? From the data sets currently available, how would the plot of total infections (from asymptomatic patients) against total infections (from symptomatic patients) look like?

Comment: This question is just too broad and depends on the circumstances.

Comment: It's reasonable to ask this question, but probably exceedingly difficult to answer it given the present knowledge. Even the closed, natural experiments like outbreaks on some ships didn't result in publications that could answer this question, but only more general questions like the ratio of asymptomatic to symptomatic infections etc. Knowing exactly who gave it to to whom and at what stage is quite difficult. See e.g. https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23573/what-information-we-have-about-transmission-of-covid-19-in-detail